# Is this a valid sorting mechanism with complexity of O(n) in python?

Tags: python, sorting

### Code

```
from functools import *
def sorter(a):
    b=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        val= reduce(lambda x,y: y if x>y else x, a)
        b.append(val)
        a.pop(a.index(val))
    return b
```

I am able to sort the data as required but is this valid approach to do so?

```
## Input
    sorter ([1,2,6,6,10,20,5,6,22,23,20,90,80])
## Output
    [1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6, 10, 20, 20, 22, 23, 80, 90]
```

Comment: What made you think this is O(n)? You iterated each element `for i in range(len(a))` and then for each element, you iterated the whole list `val = reduce(...)`, just like how baloon sort and bubble sort works. Sounds like O(n^2) instead. Not to mention the operations such as `.index()` and `.pop()`.

Comment: Why do you think this is O(n)? use sort(a) to get down to n*log(n) - which is faster then what you got.

Comment: Spoiler: There is no `O(n)` sorting algorithm for the average or worst case.

Comment: It's valid, but it's O(N^2) and it's a particularly complicated way of writing this naive algorithm. For example, the natural way to write `reduce(lambda x,y: y if x>y else x, a)` is `max(a)`.

Comment: Proving that O(N lg N) is the lower bound for comparison-based sorting, is a classic exercise in computer science. See for example https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/proving-the-lower-bound-of-compares-in-comparison-based-sorting .

Comment: You use comparison based sorting - there is no way to do it in O(n): [is-there-a-sorting-algorithm-available-which-has-time-complexity-of-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601591/is-there-a-sorting-algorithm-available-which-has-time-complexity-of-on)

Comment: Heads up that just the index and pop methods alone each is already O(N).

Comment: The code you showed in your question is an implementation of [Selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort); a well-known algorithm which takes n² operations to sort a list of n elements.

Comment: Note that `val= reduce(lambda x,y: y if x>y else x, a)` is equivalent to `val=max(a)` which uses [builtin function `max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

Answer (score 2):

`for-loop` and `reduce` method call inside it would make it `O(N^2)` operation.

```
for-loop: { <- O(N) 
   O(N) method like reduce, and index which requires iterating over the list
}
```

Noone ever devised an algorithm that sorts in `O(N)` time complexity. :)

Comment: you forgot the reduce which also iterates the list - popping may be O(1) if you pop the back element - see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: `a.index(val)` is also `O(n)`.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Yes, already noticed that it's not the last element and edited my comment.